# How do I go about separate Fade ins for each image i have here in my project?

Tags: html

[Normal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wkPxI.jpg)
[When i hover over one image all of them fade](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7hi46.jpg)

I'm not sure what I need to do to keep the effect from happening separately. Any help is appreciated.

[My styles sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ACgoQ.png)
[My index](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MP9FR.png)

I tried looking through tutorials but im just too unfamiliar with the plethora of options im given.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Relevant code and error messages need to be included in your question *as text*, [not as pictures of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/328193).  Just linking to screen shots makes it more difficult for people to help you.  Please update the question with a [mcve] as a [runnable code snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/328193) which demonstrates the problem.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Answer (score 0):

You're using `container:hover` instead of `artwork:hover`

Right now you're saying "when a container is hovered over, all .artwork within the container shall fade.